# Transform columns to factor in data frame with dplyr and regular expression

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` with >100 columns, which are all formated as numeric after importing them. I'd like to transform specific columns from numeric to factor. Instead of transforming each column manually I'd like to select the relevant columns using regular expression for the column names and transform them. With the help of [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/) I created the following expression: `\b\w{2,4}[1-9]\b`. It is supposed to select all columns where the column name is a word with 2 to 4 letters, ending with a number from 1 to 9.

Here's an example:

```
df<-data.frame(pre1=c(1:10), 
               em2=c(1:10), 
               foo=c(1:10))
df
   pre1 em2 foo
1     1   1   1
2     2   2   2
3     3   3   3
4     4   4   4
5     5   5   5
6     6   6   6
7     7   7   7
8     8   8   8
9     9   9   9
10   10  10  10

df %>%
select(matches("/\b\w{2,4]}[1-9]\b/"))
Error: '\w' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""/\b\w"
```

This should select the first two columns, but not the third. It seems that `\w` is not recognized by `matches`. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: In R, you would write your regex as `"\\b\\w{2,4}[1-9]\\b"`, but

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this all in one go quite nicely with `dplyr::mutate_at()`, defining the variables you want to change to factor with `vars()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(pre1=c(1:10), 
                 em2=c(1:10), 
                 foo=c(1:10))

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("\\b\\w{2,4}[1-9]\\b")), as.factor)

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>      pre1    em2   foo
#>    <fctr> <fctr> <int>
#>  1      1      1     1
#>  2      2      2     2
#>  3      3      3     3
#>  4      4      4     4
#>  5      5      5     5
#>  6      6      6     6
#>  7      7      7     7
#>  8      8      8     8
#>  9      9      9     9
#> 10     10     10    10
```